# Creating a 'tree like' structure with lists

Tags: c#, tree, nested-lists

Well, i have a program that works with multiple string sources and I store them in a list.
I want to trim the string at every '.' and to store the sentences obtained somewhere.
Then from the first sentence I want to trim it at every blank space and store every word somewhere.

I want to access every word later to make combinations of words, it would be great if i could access them like sources.source[2].sentence[23].level[2].word[2] or something similar.

I will make combinations like this: Jon has blue pills. (example: this is source.source[2].sentence[1] )

Jon | has | blue| pills.   (level1)

John has | has blue | blue pills .(level2)

John has blue | has blue pills .(level3)

John has blue pills. (level4)

I tried working with nested lists but i don't know how to edit at a specific index in a sublist.

Image example: http://prntscr.com/469ty2

Comment: I do not see a 'tree-like' structure in what you try doing. Why can't you not just store the sequence of single words in a simple list and access/extract any required sub-sequence of whatever length from it? (For example, if you want to deal with all sub-sequences with 3 words, pseudo-code(!) : `for (int i=0; i < sequence.Count-3; ++i) { do something with sequence[i], sequence[i+1] and sequence[i+2] }`)

Comment: I'm slightly confused... What is your question? How to split up a sentence into levels 1,2,3,4? And, if so, in your example what would `level[2].word[2]` be? `has blue` or `blue`? OR is your question how to split a source into sentences, THEN levels?

Comment: @JohnBustos level[2].word[2] = has blue , but i want to find out if there is an easier way to generate a tree structure in wich you can modify its components

Comment: You're doing this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain - use known algorithms for that.

Comment: @Jasmine No, the only problem I have is to find a structure(similar to Lists) that fits my needs, the algorithm isn't a problem.

Comment: Perhaps providing a code example of what you tried with nested lists might help shed some light on where you're having a problem. I could see a nested list structure where it's `sentence[2][2]`, where the first index is the level and the second index is the specific word or phrase.

Comment: I had something like List<string> sentence = new List<string>(); List<List<string>> source = new List<List<string>>(); source.Add(sentence); And i want to edit a specific word from it

Comment: `level` in this case should not be a property, I think - I would make it a method of the sentence class that splits up that string into the correct chunks - Store each chunk in a new class called `lvl`, say with the only property being `word = list<string>` - That should allow you to do what you want....

Comment: NO, that's not your problem. Your issue is you're doing sentence analysis and you are re-inventing how to do that. This is a known problem with a known solution. Trying to solve it yourself is the root issue. Take advantage of what the community knows about your actual problem, not the code on your screen - the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a simple starter to give you an idea of how you could build a tree structure using lists.

If you define a Fragment to represent one node in your tree, then it needs to contain a string, and a list of its children:

```
class Fragment
{
    string Content { get; set; }
    List<Fragment> Children { get; set; }
}
```

To build your tree you would create the `root` fragment with `root.Content = "John has blue pills"`.

You would then (recursively) process this fragment to subdivide it and create its children (e.g. two fragments with content "John has" and "blue Pills"). You would Add these two fragments as children of the root using `root.Children.Add()`. You would then (recursively) process each of those fragments (("John", "has") and ("blue, "pills")), and so on...

To extract data you would have to use a form like `root.Children[0].Children[1].Content` to reference something at the third level (in my example, this would return "has").

Of course, if you have a **fixed** structure (Paragraph, Sentence, Word) then you could represent the three levels like this (in pseudocode to highlight the key structure):

```
class Paragraph { List<Sentence> Sentence; }
class Sentence  { List<string>  Word;
```

...and at the root level your program would hold a `List<Paragraph> Paragraph;`.

Then your client code would be much more readable: `string word = Paragrah[2].Sentence[14].Word[5]`.